# Why is this regex expression not working on Analytics?

Tags: regex, analytics

On Analytics, I want it to filter only traffic that is `utm_source=boo`

I have tried to apply the following Regex

```
/^boo$/
```

but nothing is matching.

Comment: You are only asked to provide a *pattern*, in your case, `foo`. There is no requirement to use regex delimiters around the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Would it be? ^\Qboo\E$ it appears to be working on that expression.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the slashes:

```
boo$
```

and possibly add a leading `.*`:

```
.*boo$
```

if your tool needs to match the *whole* input.

Slashes are used as regex **delimiters** in *some* languages (eg JavaScript), but have no special meaning within regular expressions - they are just another plain character.

Your regex specified that literal slashes were required in the input.